# SSAS - Datasource view showing "-1" lengths for all numeric datatypes

Tags: ssas

When creating a datasource view any datatypes that consist of numerics are being shown in the datasource view as having a length of "-1", any character datatypes are showing correctly.

I have tried using Visual Studio 2010 and 2015 as well as using different in-house databases and the Adventure Works database and I get the same issue every time. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong but have run out of ideas and haven't been able to find anything on the net.

Example below:

1. Int32 Showing incorrect length:

[image: Int32 Showing incorrect length]

2. Str Showing correct length:

[image: Str Showing correct length]

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behaviour.  Int16, Int32 and so on include the length in their specification (16-bit integer, 32-bit integer).  The Length property is not appropriate to numeric datatypes, which is why Vs shows -1.